# Association: Task List in Workflow stopped working

Tags: 2013, workflow

Help please.

I am using SharePoint 2013 in cunjuntion with SPD (no Code). JUst OOB solution.

I have been using the  to send emails to helpdesk based on wether the Manager changes those dropdowns to Yes in his task. It has been working flawlessly up until now. The Manager would Change any of the dropdowns in any order from Default "No" to "Yes" , then when he hit Approved it would close out his Task and send emails to helpdesk.

[image: workflow screenshot]
[image: Sends email]
[image: Drop down is NO, sends anyways]

BUt Now the workflow goes right through all the stages and all the emails in the list started sending to helpdesk regardless of wether the  is changed to YES or not.

For troubleshooting I modified the workflow to only perform the first stage and have it go to complete end of workflow afterwards the result is the same, it goes through and sends an email regardless of the "No" or "Yes".

I verified the first  and even deleted and recreated it but it still sends no matter what?

I had this working perfectly up until yesterday. NOw it has stopped working and I do not know why? I did not change anything, I just added a custom site column and reorganized the stages a bit, Could I broken the workflow by reorganizing stages? (move up, move down)

Where can I start looking to troubleshoot this? Is there anything I can try?

Thank you

Mario

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the task list associated list, but it doesn't correlate with a list item. You are essentially getting only the list. You need to associate the ID with the Variable TaskID, and that should be able to find the list item.

Another thing I find is that you immediately check whether or not the Task outcome is approved. You should have a different action called "Wait for field change" to wait until the task outcome is approved before continuing.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering. I cannot use the wait because I have other helpdesk emails that need to be checked for "Yes" change and then if "Yes" then they need to run as well.

Comment: This was working fine until yesterday?

Is it possible I lost the association somehow? 

I thought that the very first string already associated the ID with TaskID 

ie.<Assign a task to Current Item:Hiring Managers (Task outcome to Variable: Outcome | Task ID to Variable: TaskID )> ?

Is there anywhere else I can check?

Thanks